Why does my PMOS FET not behave correctly when the Drain is at a lower potential then the Source? (LTSPICE sim shown)
I have a circuit I have been simulating in LTSpice for the past few days. It is a circuit that has two power sources: a battery or USBC VBUS.
My question is, do I have a misunderstanding of PMOS FETs? Does the boady diode of the FET not get reversed biased in my circuit??
The goal is to use a PMOS FET to disconnect the battery from the board if the USBC is plugged in to charge the battery. For more information on the circuit, look at the bottom of this post.
When I make the drain 0v on Q1 and set V4 high, the circuit no longer works. There are these blips when the button is pressed by the voltage is not at 5v as I expected.
The circuit works when V2 is set at a higher potential at around ~4.2v at the drain.
I would not have expected this behavior since the body diode would be reverse biased, correct??
Here are some waveforms showing when the V2 (battery) is at 4.2V, everything works:



When the PB is pressed, VFET is basically at 5v - diode drop and VOUT is 3.3V from the regulator - looks good to me. When the PB is pressed one more time, the Vout and VFET go to 0v since PMOS FET is disabled.

Here is the waveform when I make V2 = 0V or anything lower than 4.2V: (Does NOT work, lower potential after the second FET)




Here, I dropped the voltage of the battery to 3v in which we would be charging and USBC would be plugged in. And there are blips when the button is pressed but the voltage following the diode is not at ~5v as I would expect when Q2 switches on and off from the PB controller.
Since the voltage (Vout_fet) following Q2 does not stay high long enough, the push button controller U1 deasserts the enable signal - no bueno.

OPERATION OF CIRCIUT
To do this, I used the adafruit RP2040 feather as an example seen here (schematic). This essentially just uses a pull down resistor on the gate of the FET to enable the FET when no VBUS is present and when it is plugged in, the GATE goes to 5v disconnecting the battery to load.
More information in this picture of my simulation: (button represented by PWL voltage source)

EDIT: ADDITIONAL CHECKS
Here is a simplified version where the button controller is replaced by a voltage source that I can set to be 0 or 1. Looks to work. Might mean my FETs are configured correctly and I have to dig into data sheet for the controller instead.


In order for a p-ch MOSFET to operate as intended, the drain potential should be no higher than the source (otherwise, the diode will conduct). Also, the gate must be at least Vth (about -0.5V in your MOSFET) re the source voltage, or at least 0.5V lower than the source voltage to turn on the MOSFET. (Better yet, make the gate -1 to 2V re source to turn on... for lower Rds,on.)
When your battery is alive but the +5V supply is removed, the drain has a higher potential than the source, and the gate potential is zero, so both the body diode and the MOSFET conduct. (p-ch MOSFETs are usually not used that way... manufacturers generally do not provide static characteristics in that condition.)
If the +5V supply is active, the MOSFET is turned off because the gate potential is 0.6V higher than the source. The body diode remains off because the source potential (4.4V) is higher than the drain.
For simplicity I ignored the pn junction drop of 0.6-0.8V for the body diode in the above but that omission does not change the analysis.
If your intention is to keep charing the Lipo cell from 5V via 1kohm, so that the back up power is always available for a very very light load, I would recommend doing it in the way so that the maximum voltage seen by the bettery does not exceed 4.0V. Lipo cell deteriorates much faster if you charge to the full 4.20V and it gets much worse very quickly. It is even better to keep at 3.85V or 3.9V if that is adequate. The cell will last much longer. You could use two Si pn-junctions worth of drop or do more sophisticated thing there. Another approach is to use a small LiFePO4 cell directly on the 3.3V line. You need to be careful how to handle the charging current when turning the power on with an empty battery, but otherwise LiFePO4 at 3.3V is reliable and lasts for a very long time.

Thank you for your great comment, @Ryuji. So in this case, when the battery is say removed and the Drain is now lower than the source AND the gate is at 5V, then the body diode does NOT conduct and is truly reversed biased.
If this is the case, then the circuit should work even with out the battery (drain being ov) right?

In the uncommon way the PMOS is being used, when there is not gate voltage from the VBUS and the body diode and channel are conducting, the simulation seems to work as intended. It is only when the drain is lower than a certain value that it does not work unfortunately.

Please elaborate on "work" because it is not clear when you want the FET to be on or off. When the gate voltage is applied, that FET will be off, as I said in the answer. If you want to charge through the FET drain current, you need to change the gate control logic (supply 5V to the source and pull down the gate, for example).

my apologies. Work in this case means that the PMOS FET that has the battery on the Drain is indeed OFF when the VBUS pulls the GATE high as you mentioned.
I am charging the battery through another circuit and just want to disconnect the battery when I am charging it using that PMOS FET.

I was able to fix it in simulation. It seemed you were correct in the way it is setup. It was actually my KILL function that was messing with the circuit operation. I have changed this and it now works. Please see my own answer to see the change.

If that's the case, you'd accomplish the same thing using two diodes.

Good point, I wanted to use the lower drop from the FET body/diode than the diode when operating from the battery! I am only using a single cell LiPo and there is a 0.4 v dropout voltage I have to maintain. Trying to squeeze the operation time when operating from the battery as much as possible.

You could use a Schottky diode, at least on the battery side of the diode matrix. Your p-ch MOSFET is not a very reliable solution because you are passing DC in the reverse direction, which is outside what the device manufacturer expects or at least describes on the spec sheet.

I will add in a depopulated diode footprint so that if I see anything weird I can switch over. This is a prototype so going to be testing soon. Doesn’t hurt to try both or have the ability to switch if needed

Thanks to @Ryuji's answer, I was able to confirm the P channel mosfet operation in my circuit. I also learned that this is not a normal way to operate a FET.
This helped narrow down the issues seen in the simulation as it was actually the KILL function that would de-assert the active low enable for the second MOSFET if the voltage was not pulled high within a specific window.
I had a PWL voltage source on an NMOS FET that simulate a KILL command from a microcontroller set up weird as I modified it from the example .asc file.
I instead calculated a resistor feedback network to detect when the battery is around 3.2V that the threshold voltage for the KILL pin (<0.6v) is met and thus when the battery discharges too much, will turn board off automatically.
This happened to improve the circuit and accidentally remove the component causing the issues seen in the original post. It now operates even when there is no battery on Q1 and even when the battery discharges (simulated using the .step param to 3.2V, it disconnects.

